# Push String in Stack?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I am using C++ and i want to push strings in stack like push `int` in stacks.

For Example

```
3."stackoverflow"
2."is"
1."Best"
0."site"
```

at every index of stack I want to push a string. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something already? If so, could you post that as well?

Comment: "every index of stack" doesn't really make sense. Stacks aren't indexed; you only have access to the top-most element. However, there are indexed containers like `vector` which have stack-like push/pop semantics.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding here.
I want to push strings in stack.
just like to push as integers.
push("Hello");
push("world");

Answer (score 13):

Using STL, for example:

```
#include <stack>

std::stack<std::string> s;
s.push("A");
s.push("B");
s.push("C");
s.push("D");
```

Check the [STL reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

Totally agree with Ton van den Heuvel, however you said

> "at every index of stack I want to
>   push a string"

What do you mean "at every index"? You should know that once the strings are in the stack, you can only access the top string and there is no access by index in a stack. If that's what you need, use std::vector instead.

Comment: If cplusplus.com is correct (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/), the default underlying type of `std::stack` is `std::deque`, not `std::vector`. +1 anyway, but you should correct that.

Comment: @Matteo: sorry, got mixed up, vector was the default for priority_queue... editing

Answer (score 1):

I did it . I saw earlier how to convert string to character array and mixed it to what I am studying now ie. stacks.

```
stack <char> Name;
name = "mohit";
for (char c: name) {
    Name.push(c);
}
for (char c: name) {
    cout << Name.top();
    Name.pop();
}
```

And output was `tihom`.

It's function is simple. It converts string to character array and then pushes the string character by character. To pop out we use same loop and it pops out using LIFO principle.